# ¿De dónde viene la palabra "cenutrio"?

Tags: etimología, españa

[**Cenutrio**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8H6QJTt) aparece definido como:

> 1. adj. coloq. Torpe o estúpido. U. t. c. s.

¿Alguien sabe su origen?

Comment: Apruebo una edición que quedó en el limbo por [un bug](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2558/1674) que hace que las etiquetas con tildes o ñ no se vean.

Answer (score 9):

En el *Inventario General de Insultos* de Pancracio Celdrán Gomariz se indica que es una

> voz de creación expresiva, a partir del substantivo "ceniza", de la familia de los cenizos y cejijuntos, cejudos o ceñudos.

El autor comenta que, si bien su acepción actual es la de "persona boba, torpe", originalmente habría significado "persona de mala estrella" y "cargado de energía negativa", por la relación del color ceniciento con las tierras malas y los ambientes negativos y sucios. De hecho, a una planta propia de estos lugares se le dice *ceñiglo*, que es también derivado de *ceniza* y al parecer también es un insulto.

Desconozco si este comentario tiene alguna base documental o es intuición del autor, y tampoco me queda clara la relación que hace con los cejijuntos, por lo que preferiría esperar a otra respuesta que nos dé más certeza.

Comment: De hecho en España se usa también bastante [_cenizo_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8DfJYXc) para denominar a alguien que da mala suerte o que es algo... cenutrio.

Comment: @fedorqui En Chile no conocemos _cenutrio_ ni _cenizo_. A los que tienen mala suerte les decimos _yeta_ y a los torpes... bueno, _güevón_.

Comment: Para añadir a éste último comentario de Rodrigo, en Colombia a los de mala suerte les decimos _salados_  _"y a los torpes... bueno, _güevón_"._  :-D

Answer (score 7):

Por dar más alternativas, voy a exponer aquí el contenido de las fichas del Fichero General de la RAE que hablan sobre el tema:

> **cenutrio<sup>1</sup>.** (De *caenum, -i*, cieno, lodo. En Plauto y Cicerón, inmundicia [término injurioso].) m. fig. Hombre despreciable, salido del fango.
>
> **cenutrio<sup>2</sup>.** (Influido por *cenurosis*, en Veterinaria infección por el "*caenurus* cerebralis" de las reses lanares y vacunas.) m. fig. Hombre lerdo, tosco, zafio.
>
> 1974 SERNA,J.S.Dicc.manchego

Al igual que pasa con [la respuesta anterior](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21337/12637), ignoro la validez de estas afirmaciones. No hay muchos más datos porque el término parece reciente. La primera aparición en diccionarios es de finales del siglo XX. De hecho en el CORDE no hay casos y en el CREA el primero es de 1981:

> *El gorderas, con una sonrisita de cenutrio, va y le pregunta que si está segura de que no tiene gas en su casa.*
>
> Carlos Pérez Merinero, "Días de guardar", 1981 (España).

En Ngram [el primer caso](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cenutrio&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccenutrio%3B%2Cc0) es de 1975:

> *—Ese. Un cenutrio sin pizca de cerebro.*
>
> Francisco Carantoña Alvarez, "La libertad de los tejones", 1975 (España).

Y en la hemeroteca de la BNE no hay tampoco ningún caso. Es lo malo de los términos de reciente cuño, que es más difícil seguirles el rastro por la velocidad con que se crea la información. En todo caso, sabemos que en 1974 ya estaba documentada (el *Inventario General de Insultos* es de 1995).

En todo caso, una de las fichas me pone sobre la pista de una palabra relacionada: *cenorio*. Esta no aparece en el diccionario pero sí en otra ficha que afirma que es un "sobrenombre que se aplica a la persona muy *abulto o ignorante". Y me redirige a *[acenoria](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0N7s1Kh)*, que es una forma rural poco usada de *zanahoria* (corrupción de *[azanoria](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4dpcdcR)*, y esta corrupción aragonesa de *zanahoria*). Por lo tanto esto le da al término un posible origen rural relacionado con las verduras, como puedan ser *lechuguino* o *ceporro* (de *cepa*).

Curiosamente, llamar a alguien *[zanahoria](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cKSv2BC)* en algunos países de América implicaría llamarle "persona tonta y simplona". En mi opinión este posible origen proveniente de *zanahoria* me resulta más plausible que el de "influido por *cenurosis*". Quedaría así:

```
zanahoria >> azanoria >> acenoria >> cenorio >> cenotrio >> cenutrio
```

Problema: no veo casos ni de "cenotrio" ni de "cenorio" ni en el CORDE ni en Ngram. Así que o bien me equivoco o bien las versiones previas no se popularizaron y no quedaron en textos escritos.

Answer (score 3):

La "**fenilcetonuria**" es una enfermedad rara que si no se trata en recién nacidos causa de discapacidad intelectual.

Su origen viene del latín "**fenilis**" "**cenutrius**", *acúmulo de deshechos*, se cree que la relación de esta enfermedad con un fenotipo de retraso mental ha llevado a utilizar "**cenutrio**" en el lenguaje coloquial español.